# Jquery get same value text boxes?

Tags: jquery, jquery-selectors

In below table I have scenario dropdown and identifer text boxes is their, How can I write a selector to get same identifer value text boxes?

[image]

Answer (score 0):

use jquery **`filter`** method

```
$(".txtbox").filter(".05-vl-94")
```

same way you can filter value by the group you want to create